# Laravel 8 decrypt

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-8, public-key-encryption

***I try to do decrypt value ?  But it is giving this error. The payload is invalid.***

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

$identity_no = "eyJpdiI6Inhzakt4SE10Mk1TbGVNakZKb29nc2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaW9tWGVhOXZaQWlCYzhBbmNrbTV3dXdQYmNrTmt1S3dHKzdqelNLcFppbVJoR2s3NmptaVlKaU4rc1NSU3F2MW1oSVlJdU9OTEJuT05w ▶";

$decrypted_identityno = Crypt::decryptString($identity_no);


dd($decrypted_identityno);
die();
```

Comment: But data is encrypted data @Espresso

Comment: The issue is the payload doesn't contain the necessary information for the decrypter to work. The decrypter will bail out if the payload doesn't have the proper keys. You can look at the comment in the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c11ecea4aff3f19ca4225581443618dd09274c85/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L188) for more information.

Comment: If you have this string, then its should be long, check the last of this string `$identity_no = "eyJpdiI6Inhzakt4SE10Mk1TbGVNakZKb29nc2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaW9tWGVhOXZaQWlCYzhBbmNrbTV3dXdQYmNrTmt1S3dHKzdqelNLcFppbVJoR2s3NmptaVlKaU4rc1NSU3F2MW1oSVlJdU9OTEJuT05w ▶` there are more alphabets `▶`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel encrypting and decrypting text via OpenSSL using AES-256 and AES-128 encryption, so every time you encrypt it will give you a unique result. You can decrypt a string after you get the value from the encrypt method :

```
$identity_value = "1234";
$identity_no = Crypt::encryptString($identity_value);
$decrypted_identityno = Crypt::decryptString($identity_no);
dd($decrypted_identityno);
```

> Encrypted payload must be different each time, even if the same
> plaintext is encrypted. Laravel does it properly